# Selling multiple apps in a bundle on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, app-bundle

I understand that Google Play does not support app bundles. Is there a workaround that can achieve the same effect ? I have several apps on Play Store but would like to also sell them at a discount if the user purchases all of them at once.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: You would have to move to a subscription or in app purchase model where the apps could detect which of your other apps are installed and apply discounts at runtime.

Comment: Another way you could do this is by building with something like React-Native in components. Each of your apps could be a main component. Then for your bundle, you could have it be just a home screen with X number of icons on it which modally display the other apps. Technically speaking, the user won't have a bundle of individual apps. They would have a single app that holds multiple apps within it. Of course, you couldn't discount for apps already owned unless the wrapper was free to download, and you could buy apps as IAPs (or detect the user already owns them on their device, giving access)